# How can I simplify this rails controllers for content pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following class, but it has a lot of duplicate code. Is there a way to simplify this so that I don't have to add a new method for each page record (this would also allow clients to add pages at will). Here is the current controller:

```
    class StaticController < ApplicationController
      def privacy_policy
        @page = Page.find_by_slug 'privacy_policy'
        render 'static/page'
      end

      def terms
        @page = Page.find_by_slug 'terms'
        render 'static/page'
      end

      def about
        @page = Page.find_by_slug 'about'
        render 'static/page'
      end
    end
```

Comment: better for codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

You could write a class method in your Page model:

```
def self.page_by_slug(slug)
  Page.find_by_slug(slug)
end
```

And in your StaticController, you can pass in a parameter (based on a user action) and render the static page with a before_action callback:

```
class StaticController < ApplicationController
  before_action :render_static_page

  def static_page
    @page = Page.page_by_slug(params[:slug])
  end

  private
  def render_static_page
   render 'static/page'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `before_action` at the top of your controller.

```
class StaticController < ApplicationController
    before_action :_render_template, :only => [:privacy_policy, :terms, :about]

    def privacy_policy
      @page = Page.find_by_slug 'privacy_policy'
    end

    def terms
      @page = Page.find_by_slug 'terms'
    end

    def about
      @page = Page.find_by_slug 'about'
    end

    private
    def _render_template
       render 'static/page'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add a catch all route to your application, it's important that the route is the last thing in your routes file as it will catch every url:

```
match '*slug' => 'static#show'
```

Remove any static routes you've defined for the original 3 actions from your routes file, they're no longer needed.

Next modify your static controller as follows:

```
class StaticController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @page = Page.find_by_slug(params[:slug])
    render 'static/page'
  end

end
```

I've ommitted any checking for existence of the page etc... I'll leave that up to you ;)